# What is the light source in the 19th century submarine?

Tags: realism, 20000-leagues-under-the-sea

In ***20000 Leagues Under the Sea***, the timeline of the plot sets it in the 19th century.

Edison invented the light bulb at the beginning of the 20th century, but this movie is set even before.

What must be the light source in the 19th Century submarine then?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The light source is explained in the Jules Verne book.  Although, as you say, in the film the light is simply taken for granted.

In several Jules Verne books, he refers to a light source called a [Ruhmkorff Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Daniel_Ruhmkorff).
This is an early form of fluorescent light and did exist in this period of the 19th century.

The Ruhmkorff lamp was somewhat cumbersome, so when incandescent bulbs came along, it rapidly became obsolete.